# Javascript class in closure

Tags: javascript, class, closures

I'm writing a JavaScript closure that contains classes and looks a bit like this:

```
// myClosure.js
var myClosure = (function() {

    class myClass {
        constructor(val) {
            this.myValue = val;
        }

        myFunc() {
            console.log("myClass says: " + this.myValue);
        }
    }

    this.myClass = myClass;
});
```

I'd like to 'import' this closure into another JavaScript file and instantiate a `myClass`. I tried this:

```
// myApp.js
$.getScript('myModule.js', function(myClosure) {
    var myClassInstance = new myClosure.myClass(7);
}
```

but I get an error claiming that `myClosure.myClass` is not a constructor.

Can someone please point to a simple example, or a better way of doing this altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, myClosure returns nothing, so you will never be able to access it. In your example you could just return this.

Next, you have not executed the closure, you can do this by putting `()` at then end to make it into an IFFE..

Below is an example.

```js
// myClosure.js
var myClosure = (function() {
    class myClass {
        constructor(val) {
            this.myValue = val;
        }
        myFunc() {
            console.log("myClass says: " + this.myValue);
        }
    }
    this.myClass = myClass;
    return this; //add this
}()); //and <- () that.



var myClassInstance = new myClosure.myClass(7);

myClassInstance.myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to export this function first to include it in another javascript file.

if you are using node simply use module.exports = function name  or for es6 you can use export default

and in another file simply import it

Answer (score 0):

- `this` doesn't work anything like that
- `myClosure` is a function which doesn't create a closure
- The first argument to the callback to `getScript` is a string containing the script. It isn't a value from the script.

To get values from it, you need to access a global.

Typically, if you were using jQuery.getScript, it would look something like this:

```
// myModule.js
class myClass {
    // etc
}

// main.js
$.getScript('myModule.js', function () {
    const myInstance = new myClass(7);
});
```

---

Modern code would tend towards using ES6 modules:

```
// myModule.js
class myClass {
    // etc
}
export default myClass;

// main.js
import myClass from "./myModule.js";
const myInstance = new myClass(7);

// HTML
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

… although that sacrifices Internet Explorer support, in which cases you would want to look at using a bundler tool like Webpack.